# Extracting contents using Tika transformation - Manifold CF

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-tika, documentum, manifoldcf

We are indexing Documentum contents to Elasticsearch using Manifold Cf. we are not able to get the contents from attachment, but metadata is available.

Is there any way to get the contents using Tika transformation? Or please suggest some ways to get the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding "content" into the "Schema" tab in Output Connections?
This will be for the field "Content field name:"

Also, are you using internal tika or external for Manifold CF?

Comment: we added tika code to our output connector and fixed the issue.